# Compiling Groovy class with existing java classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I have existing java web application. Now I have written a  groovy hello world class. How should I compile it with existing java class?  From http://groovy.codehaus.org/ looks like I need a different compiler for this as command is groovy -e "println 'Hello ' + args[0]" World
 instead use javac.

I want to compile command from both command prompt and eclipse so that groovy class gets compiled with existing java classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building with Eclipse I guess you need to install the Groovy plugin and make sure it is seeing your project as a groovy project.

I'm not sure how to do this, as like Arturo, I just use Sublime Text and the command line.

For compiling from the command line, you should be using something like Ant ([documentation can be found here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovyc+Ant+Task) for the groovyc task and cross-compiling with Java), or Gradle ([documentation here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html) on the Groovy plugin)

Comment: Yes. Install plugin and add Groovy nature to the product in the preferences

Answer (score 5):

You need to use joint compilation in Groovy, to attach javac compiler to compile .java files.

Use `-j` option with groovyc compiler:

```
groovyc *.groovy *.java -j
```

Comment: Thanks Arturo Herrero. Actually i am interested other way around. i mean want to attach groovy compiler to compile groovy files as i have hundread of existing java file and only one groovy file. What modification i need to do in eclipse compilation setting to also compile new groovy file.

Comment: Sorry, I mainly use command line and Sublime text editor. I can't help you with the Eclipse configuration.